# changing json output when using serializer

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, nsjsonserialization

i want to ask, when i clicked the button and then println the json data appear like that picture..

[image]

i want to ask if it possible to change the output like this

> {"telur" : "4" , "roti" : "4"}
>        {"softball" : "60" , "senam" : "60"}

in the other way, i want to make it one bracket and erase type and amount in it, I'm using jsonserializer though..

the code like this..

menu.swift

```
class Nutritiondata
{
    var type = "type"
    var amount = 0
    //var date = "Date"
    init (type: String, amount: Int)
    {
        self.type = type
        self.amount = amount
        //self.date = date
    }
}

class Activitiesdata
{
    var type = "type"
    var amount = 0
    //var date = "Date"
    init (type: String, amount: Int)
    {
        self.type = type
        self.amount = amount
        //self.date = date
    }
}
```

table view

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



        let cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell
        let menu = arrayOfMenu[indexPath.row]
        cell.setCell(menu.type, rightlabeltext: menu.unit, imagename: menu.image)
        var data = Nutritiondata(type: menu.type, amount: String(cell.value ).toInt()!)
        var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(data)
        JSONNutrisi.jsondata = json
        return cell
    }

var data = Nutritiondata(type: leftlabel.text!, amount: qtytext.text.toInt()!)
        var temp:Nutritiondata
        temp = data
        var idx = 0
        if(temp.amount-1 > 0) {
            temp.amount -= 1
        }
        data = Nutritiondata(type: leftlabel.text!, amount: qtytext.text.toInt()!)
        var json = JSONSerializer.toJson(data)
        var tempJson = JSONSerializer.toJson(temp)
        for(var i = 0; i < Nutritionmenu.data.count; i++){
            if(Nutritionmenu.data[i] == tempJson){
                self.check = true
                self.idx = i
            }
        }
```

Comment: see my answer, may be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make one `struct` function which have `type` and `amount`

```
struct Nutritiondata {

    let type :String
    let amount : Int

    func Dict(age : Int) -> Nutritiondata
    {
        return Nutritiondata(type: type, amount: amount)
    }
}
```

Now take one array and store the data in it. here I am store static data but you store the data from response

```
let alldata = [Nutritiondata(type: "telur", amount: 4),Nutritiondata(type: "roti", amount: 4),Nutritiondata(type: "softball", amount: 60),Nutritiondata(type: "seman", amount: 60)]
```

Now you can use the data as below.

```
alldata[0].type   // telur

alldata[0].amount // 4
```

use this alldata in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

```
let nutrition = alldata[indexPath.row]
```

you can display in tableview using below code

```
nutrition.type
nutrition.amount
```